# Get data from shared memory after getting signal from child process

Tags: c, signals, fork, shared-memory

```
int *sharedmem(key_t *key,char k,int size){
  int shmid;
  int *segptr;
  *key=ftok('.',k);
  if((shmid=shmget(*key,size,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666))==-1){
    printf("Shared memory segment exists - opening as client\n");
    if((shmid = shmget(*key, size, 0)) == -1){
      perror("bad shmget");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  else
    printf("Creating new shared memory segment\n");
  if((segptr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == NULL){
    perror("bad shmat");
    exit(1);
  }
  return segptr;
}
int main(){
  ...
  mem=sharedmem(&key,'a',2);
  fpid=getpid();
  signal(SIGHUP,sighup);
  if(pid=fork()==0){
    ...
    mem[0]=1;
    kill(fpid,SIGHUP);
  }
  else {//parent
     //read data from mem[0] when receiving the signal.
  }
```

How can I read the data from mem[0] in parent upon receiving the signal from the child process?
I want to notify the parent that the data has been written to the shared memory and the parent can read it.

Comment: When the parent's signal handler returns, the parent can simply read the data.  It might mean using one of the 'wait for a signal' calls (`pause()`, `sigwait()`, etc), or maybe the parent has some other work to do.  At some point, it needs to check a flag set in the signal handler to indicate that there is data ready.

Comment: my suggestion:  loose all the signal processing.  use a mutex, have two data items in shared memory  one says that data is available that is set by child and read by parent.  The second contains the actual data 'mem[0]'/  parent clears the memory locations before starting child.  child, when ready, locks mutex, sets the data, sets the 'available' flag, unlocks mutex.  parent locks mutex, checks flag, if flag set, read data endif, unlock mutex

Answer (score 0):

In your parent, you can just read the shared data within the signal handler. However, depending on what you want to do with this data, you might want to adopt a different strategy. For instance:

- Increment a global static variable in your signal handler (make it a `volatile sig_atomic_t`). Then in them main loop of your program test this, and take action appropriately.
- Nicer, use a *self pipe*. Explanation [here](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html). In essence create a non-blocking `pipe()` and write a character to it from your signal handler. `select()` on the read side of the pipe in the normal way in your main loop.
- If your parent process is multithreaded, consider abandoning the signal handler and use semaphores or similar.